# How to link my stackoverflow profile with arbitrary third party identity sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Suppose I were in charge of linking StackOverflow/StackExchange to [Keybase.io](https://keybase.io), [onename.com](https://onename.com/), or another identity service. What would be the best way to "prove" that I own [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418413/kojiro)?

One way that could work today is if I post some arbitrary string in the "about me" section of my profile. But that would muddy up my profile some.

Another way would be for me to post a question with my identity proof in it. (I say this for completeness' sake, but we all know it's a terrible idea.)

The third approach, and the final one I've been able to come up with, is chat dedicated to identity proofs.

Is this something SO is interested in helping make more possible? What other ways could it be done?

Comment: *chat dedicated to identity proofs* - I'm not sure what this means. Are you talking about creating a chat room that you invite a rep from one of those 3rd parties to in order to prove that you are you?

Comment: @BSMP yes, but the rep would be a bot. The room could persist for others to make their proofs in, or it could be ephemeral, I guess, depending on what works best for SO.

Comment: Yes, add info to your profile.  Once you are positively identified by this, you can revert your edit.  Tada.

Comment: @Will that's not ideal, because that identification is also used by apps to help individual users trust your identity. For example, `keybase track bob` would list bob's public proofs so you can be sure you got the bob you wanted. If those proofs are deleted, Keybase may believe it's you, but its users may not.

Comment: Or you could [use the api and register as an app](http://stackoverflow.com/users/apps/418413).  That would positively identify the user to an application.